# Are pregnant women forbidden from eating harmful vegetables?

Tags: halacha, food, pregnancy-birth

There are many things that we can’t do because of danger - the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch even has an [entire Siman](http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1650&ArticleID=7082) on the topic.

Sifrei Bamidbar 87 states that certain vegetables are harmful to pregnant women:

> ר' שמעון אומר מפני מה המן משתנה להם לכל דבר שהיו רוצים חוץ מחמשת המינים הללו? משל למלך בשר ודם שמסר בנו לפדגוג, והיה יושב ומפקדו ואומר לו: הנראה שלא יאכל מאכל רע, ולא ישתה משקה רע! ובכל כך היה הבן ההוא מתרעם על אביו, לומר: לא מפני שאוהבני, אלא שאי אפשר לו שאוכל.

In summary, the passuk (Bamidbar 11:5) states that the complainers missed their cucumbers, melons, leeks, onion, and garlic. On this, R’ Shimon gives a parable to a king who wouldn’t give his son food that was harmful to him, and the son said it was because the king was unable to give it to him, not because it was bad for him; so, too, the man was incapable of turning into these foods. Rashi (ad. loc.) understands this to mean that they’re dangerous for pregnant women.

Throwing these two sources together: since we are forbidden against doing certain dangerous things, and these foods are dangerous for pregnant women, is there a formal prohibition against pregnant women eating these foods?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think these are actually/still dangerous?

Comment: I don't get what the question is. If those are dangerous, and it's forbidden to eat dangerous foods, then yes, it's forbidden to eat those foods.

Comment: @DoubleAA As far as I can tell, meat/fish isn’t harmful, but many (most?) groups still hold of that.

Comment: @donie old habits die hard... there's indeed no formal prohibition or danger nowadays. Whether it's a formal minhag or not is debatable.

Comment: @Salmononius2 The common thread is that those things are forbidden because of danger - there’s never an explicit Halacha that we should avoid dangerous things, so much as avoiding these things which are inherently dangerous. I’m sorry if I’m not being clear. All I’m asking is that the same way we explicitly forbid meat and fish together because they’re dangerous, is there an explicit source that pregnant women should avoid these things?

Comment: @doniel but we don't explicitly forbid meat and fish together. It's just a commonly listed example with a whole bunch of other examples that don't make any medical sense.

Comment: @DoubleAA So why not list other examples brought down in Chazal, regardless of if they make medical sense?

Comment: @doni indeed many codifiers do list other examples, and many don't even list this one. You've probably heard of some other ones, like onions left overnight or spilling a drink.